# How to add a new file in common folder in opencart

Tags: php

I want to add a new `.tpl` file in opencart's common folder. As I see there are 12 files in common folder and all are define in `home.tpl` file and `home.php` file that are header,footer, breadcrumb, column_left,column_right and so on.

So how could I add a new file in common folder and define it to show its content in my website home page.